# Nashorn: how do I distinguish between a javascript object and a java object?

Tags: nashorn

I am trying to work out how to distinguish between a javascript object and a java object inside a script running on Nashorn.

I ended up writing something like this:

```
function isJavaObject(oj) {
    return oj.getClass && oj.hashCode 
}
```

Is there a better way ?

Note that using instanceof against java.lang.Object does not work

```
oj = {} 
oj instanceof Java.type("java.lang.Object")  // returns true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nashorn has a non-ECMA-standard built-in object "Java" (capital "J") that has a lot of goodies, among them the `Java.isJavaObject(obj)` function that returns true if the specified object is a Java object but not a script object. There is also `Java.isScriptObject(obj)` that returns almost the exact opposite, except for `null` for which both functions return `false`.

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly what I was after.

Comment: Out of curiosity do you know if there is some documentation is for the built-in object "Java" ? thanks